# How can I mark videos as read in my YouTube subscriptions without opening them?

Tags: youtube

[image: Picture of YouTube Subscription Box]

I use the YouTube Subscription Service to follow Channels. The only way I know to remove "new" videos from the sidebar is by opening and closing them. I would like to mark all videos of a channel (or all videos in my subscription) as read. This would help me differentiate new and skipped videos.

I'd take a script as well if it's impossible within the site itself.

Comment: There is no longer a number next to the subscription, now it is a blue dot (in the new youtube format).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because YouTube have changed a lot since this question was posted and this looks to be obsolete. Current related help articles: YouTube subscriptions [Subscribe to YouTube channels](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4489286?hl=en), [Manage YouTube notifications](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3382248?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

The only workaround that occurs to me is to save them to a list, say, named "not interested", and leave your computer one day playing the list at fast speed. Also maybe a script could play each video on the list just enough minutes to be marked as seen, and then delete them from the list. On the other, I'm not sure  if you mark them as not interested, when you are still subscribed to the channel, I think they wont appear as recommendations, but the new ones will still show.